# Make class elements accessible in companion object

Tags: scala

I need to access the list object in `someFunction` below, however I get a compilation error `not found: value list`. How to access the list from the companion object?

```
class HelloScala {
  val list = List (1,2,3)
}

object HelloScala {

     def someFunction  = {
       println(list)
     }

}
```

Comment: This makes no sense. There may be many instances of `HelloScala` class. Which of them should the object access? If they are the same for all instances, make them member of the object instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to access members of a class, you have to instantiate that class:

```
object HellowScala {
  def someFunction = {
    println(new HelloScala().list)
  }
}
```

More likely, what you want to do is move the list member to the companion object:

```
class HelloScala {
   // you can access the companion members here
   val x = HelloScala.list
}

object HelloScala {

  val list = List (1,2,3)

  def someFunction  = {
    println(list)
  }
}
```